# Android, pegar id de um item de uma listView através do clique longo

Tags: android, listview

alguém sabe como faço para puxar um ID de um item da ListView através do `SetOnItemLongClickListener` e poderiam me dizer se esse método funcionaria com um item que esta sendo exibido do banco de dados??

O código do Adapter:

```
public class ObjetoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Objeto> objeto;

private Context context;

public ObjetoAdapter(Context context, List<Objeto> objeto) {
    this.objeto = objeto;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objeto.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return objeto.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return objeto.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.lista_objetos, parent, false);

    TextView tvID = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvID);
    TextView tvNome = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvLvNome);
    TextView tvValor = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvLvValor);

    Objeto objetoDaVez = objeto.get(position);

    tvID.setText("ID: " + getItemId(position));
    tvNome.setText(" Nome" + objetoDaVez.getNome());
    tvValor.setText(" Valor: R$" + objetoDaVez.getValor());

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ficou um pouco difícil de entender, mas se entendi bem, você quer pegar o id do seu objeto e não simplesmente a posição dele na listview, como é recebido no parâmetro do Listener. Então, vamos lá...

Na interface OnItemLongClickListener temos o método onItemLongClick que recebe como parâmetro uma instância de AdapterView. Através dessa instância podemos capturar do adapter usado na listview através do comando `adapterView.getAdapter()`. Tendo o adapter em mãos podemos invocar o método `adapter.getItemId(int posicao)`, que geralmente sobrescrevemos quando o adapter é customizado. Se você sobrescrever esse método no seu adapter, poderá ter o id, seja ele qual for, do seu objeto referenciado pelo item da listview que foi clicado e não necessariamente a posição do item na lista.

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int pos, long id) {
        long codigoDoObjeto = adapterView.getAdapter().getItemId(pos);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Vou colocar aqui um exemplo do adapter customizado:

```
public class MeuObjetoListListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<MeuObjeto> meuObjetoList;

public SistemaListViewAdapter(Context context, List<MeuObjeto> meuObjetoList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.meuObjetoList= meuObjetoList;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return meuObjetoList.get(position).getCodigoIdOuPKQualquer();
}

//Demais métodos ...

}
```

Se não for isso, peço desculpas, mas foi o que entendi =)

Comment: Talvez seja isso (Não posso testar no momento), pra ficar claro, o que quero, eu desejo pegar pegar o ID do objeto da LV no banco (através do clique longo), para poder, por exemplo, usar esse ID e exibir o nome e valor do objeto (que consta no banco) referente ao ID numa outra Activity em duas TextView, deu pra entender ou continua confuso??

Comment: Acredito então que o que citei seja o caminho certo.  Você quer pegar o id do objeto, que é a primary key no banco de dados, e não a posição dele na ListView. Qual adapter você está usando em sua ListView?

Comment: Depois de o método `getItemId` ter sido implementado passa a ser possível pegar directamente o valor do `id` através do parâmetro passado ao método `onItemLongClick`.

Comment: certo, Tássio, dei uma fuçada aqui no código e meu código está aparentemente identico ao seu, estou utilizando o BaseAdapter. Me parece que esse é o caminho mesmo, então nesse caso, como eu poderia fazer para que ao clique  longo, ele armazene o id em uma variável para que em uma outra Activity, ele possa ser passado como parametro para o meu método `buscarObjetoPorID(variavel)`?

Comment: Para ressaltar, fiz do jeito que você fez e ai no método setei o `Objeto.getId()` e ele me retornou o primeiro item independente de qual eu clique.

Comment: Sim, por esse caminho você pode pegar o id (primary key da tabela) do seu objeto. Sobre seu novo problema, precisaria ver parte do seu código do adapter para entender o que está acontecendo. Teria como mostrar?

Comment: Claro, após sua demonstração e o comentário do Ramaral, mudei o trecho do código do ID e coloquei aquele `getItemId(position)` pra ver se funcionava e na ListView, abaixo de cada objeto, aparece o ID referente, mas ainda não sei como pegar o ID, uma vez que tentei instanciar esse adapte e não deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

Se o *adaptar* associado à sua *ListView* for um *CursorAdaptar* o parâmetro `id` passado ao método `onItemLongClick()`, da interface *OnItemLongClickListener*, representa o valor do campo *_id* do registo associado à linha clicada.

```
private long listItemPressedId;
minhaList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
            int pos, long id) {
        listItemPressedId = id; //id do registo associado à linha clicada
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Fala, Ramaral, agradeço a tentativa, mas não deu certo (A única opção que apareceu foi `ListItem` e nem assim deu certo), vamos ver se explicando você consegue ajudar. Cada linha da LV exibe dados de um banco de dados, aí queria que ao clicasse no item(certo dado), ele pegasse o ID do item, verificasse no banco de quem era esse ID e fosse para uma outra tela exibir apenas esse item. Nesse método de exibir na outra tela usei um ID já existente e funcionou, porém quero que ao longo clique, ele pegue o ID do selecionado, deu pra entender??

Comment: O que quer dizer com *"A única opção que apareceu foi ListItem..."*?

Comment: Quando fui fazer a sintaxe que você recomendou (com `ListItemPressedId`), o mais perto que apareceu foi `ListItem` e nada mais do gênero, compreendeu??

Comment: `listItemPressedId` é a variável que vai guardar o `id` do item da lista clicado. Você deve declará-la primeiro como `private long listItemPressedId`

Comment: Ah sim, entendi, mas no caso, essa variável do tipo long seria usada em um método que precisaria de um int (o ID do banco), teria de fazer uma conversão de long para int normalmente ou com long é diferente (Não conheço muito esse tipo)?

Comment: Não é preciso fazer conversão, o tipo `long` é um `int` com uma maior amplitude de valores(guarda números maiores). Tenha em atenção que o código postado parte do princípio que o seu *adapter* herda de *CursorAdpater* (ou *SimpleCursorAdapter*) o que é o aconselhado quando se trabalha com dados vindos do SQLite.

Comment: Ah sim, mas meu banco não é o SQlite e sim o MySql (Ele roda a partir da internet), tem algum problema ou funcionaria da mesma maneira?

Comment: Como é que você acede ao banco?

Comment: Utilizo uma WebService, o `strictmode.threadpolicy` para o app puxar remotamente os dados, um método para buscar todos os objetos de uma tabela do banco e adapto o ListView para cada linha aparecer um objeto e esse método que desejo executar seria um `SELECT nome, valor WHERE ID = X` (Se foi isso mesmo o que perguntou).

Comment: Como o seu *adapter* não é um *CursorAdapter* terá de implementar o método `getItemId()` no seu *adapter*. veja a resposta do Tássio Auad.